# The column name email was not found in this ResultSet

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I'm doing a dynamic query with **NativeQuery**, where you return one or many columns values. The columns name to be consulted are sent by user through the body of an Endpoint. The query I created is as follow:

**PostgreSQL Script**

```
SELECT :selection FROM myScheme.myTable
```

**NativeQuery Script**

```
String selection = "d.id, d.name";
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.append("SELECT " + selection + " FROM myTable d ");
Query query = em.createNativeQuery(builder.toString());
List<Tuple> services = query.getResultList();
```

**DTO**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class myDTO  {

   private int id;
   private String name;
   private String email;
}
```

While executing my code, I'm getting this error:

```
The column name email was not found in this ResultSet
```

**UPDATED**

I might guess, I'm getting that error because my query is only querying by d.id and d.name (which is fine) since selection doesn't contain the **d.email**. The **id** an **name** fields of my DTO Class are being filled in, but email don't, so that the error, isn't it?

Comment: You either need to add an `email` column to your query, or you need to define an explicit result set mapping, or you need to define a DTO without a `email` field.

Answer (score 1):

You have to fill in the selection with your email. Like this:
"String selection = "d.id, d.name, d.email";"
Or
You must define a value that will be equivalent to the column.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain myself well. I just updated the post. But what u mean is if in my query I'm missing the email column it'l throw The column name email was not found in this ResultSet right?